# how to allow root log on on console on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ssh

I can ssh into my system as my normal user (non-root) and `sudo` to root, but on on  `vm-guest-console` on vCenter, I'm not able to log in as a root.

What setting is required to allow root log in to console?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

grep PermitRoot  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Comment: if server is having network issue and you need to troubleshoot server on console. all other account are work only if server communicate LDAP server. reboot server in rescue mode is last option . while server is up and running- you want to log in as a root on console

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow login as the root user only on the "console" and not on ssh, simply login as your normal user and set a password for your user root.

```
$ sudo su -
# passwd
```

Comment: this is working.  i want to logon on console ( on vCenter ) as aroot. because server is having network issue.

Comment: Hello, can you clarify if the proposed solution solved the problem or if you need further help ?

Comment: proposed solution has not solve the issue to log on on console